# Exceptions while coverting CSV to ORC

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, orc, bigdata

I am trying to write a mapreduce program which takes input as CSV and writes as ORC format but facing NullPointerException exception.

Below is the exception stack trace i am getting

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:406)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.WriterImpl.createTreeWriter(WriterImpl.java:1584)

at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.WriterImpl.<init>(WriterImpl.java:176)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcFile.createWriter(OrcFile.java:369)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcNewOutputFormat$OrcRecordWriter.write(OrcNewOutputFormat.java:51)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcNewOutputFormat$OrcRecordWriter.write(OrcNewOutputFormat.java:37)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:558)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:85)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:106)
at ORCMapper.map(ORCMapper.java:22)
at ORCMapper.map(ORCMapper.java:1)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:140)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:672)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:268)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Following is the code for mapreduce job

/** driver code**/

```
public class RunORC extends Configured implements Tool {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new RunORC(), args);
        System.exit(res);

    }

    public int run(String[] arg) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf=getConf();

        //Set ORC configuration parameters
        conf.set("orc.create.index", "true");


        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
        job.setJarByClass(RunORC.class);
        job.setJobName("ORC Output");


        job.setMapperClass(ORCMapper.class);
       // job.setReducerClass(OrcReducer.class);
        //job.setNumReduceTasks(Integer.parseInt(arg[2]));
        job.setNumReduceTasks(0);

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Writable.class);

       // job.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
       // job.setOutputValueClass(Writable.class);
       job.setOutputFormatClass(OrcNewOutputFormat.class);



        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(arg[0]));
        Path output=new Path(arg[1]);

    //   OrcNewOutputFormat.setCompressOutput(job,true);
        OrcNewOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,output);

        return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0: 1;
    }


}
```

/** mapper code **/

```
    public class ORCMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,NullWritable,Writable> {

        private final OrcSerde serde = new OrcSerde();

        @Override
        protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

             Writable row = serde.serialize(value, null);
                   context.write(NullWritable.get(), row);
                }
        //}
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You invoke OrcSerde.serialize method with null second argument, I bet this is the reason. Look here for example:
http://hadoopcraft.blogspot.com/2014/07/generating-orc-files-using-mapreduce.html

Comment: Hey thanks .. it worked , but i was wondering why do i need to send the second parameter.